# How to change React component tag to jsx tag name with condition properly?

Tags: reactjs

I'm a newbie in React, so don't judge me)

I have a slider which I get from react-flickity-component,

and now I need to make some condition,

if my boolean attribute is correct turn off slider,

I know how to make it in javascript, but no thoughts in react how destroy it,

So I get an idea just change tag name.

So I have:

```
class FlickitySlider extends React.Component {
...
  render() {
...
    return (
      <Flickity options={flickityOptions}>
        ...content
      </Flickity>
    );
  }
}
```

And I have an attribute called `editView`,

so when it's true turn off slider by changing

`<Flickity></Flickity>` to `<div></div>`,
I know I can do smth like this:

```
return (
   {editView ?
      <Flickity options={flickityOptions}>
        ...content
      </Flickity>
   :
      <div>
        ...content
      </div>
   }
);
```

But duplicate content two times, not a good practice.

Is it possible to make smth like this, but properly:

```
return (
   {editView ?
      <Flickity options={flickityOptions}>
   :
      <div>
   }
        ...content
   {editView ?
      </Flickity>
   :
      </div>
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'd recommend that you declare whatever `content` is:

```
function renderContent() {
  return content;
}

return (
   {editView ?
      <Flickity options={flickityOptions}>
        {renderContent()}
      </Flickity>
   :
      <div>
        {renderContent()}
      </div>
   }
);
```

That's probably as clean as you're going to get

Comment: I'm trying, but can't make it work, no any errors in my terminal.
I'm using arrow function like this:
const renderContent = () => {
  return (
    <div>asdasd</div>
    <div>qwerr</div>
  )
}
And all I'm getting nothing inside renderContent. @imjared